# Effective search in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search

```
 public ActionResult ViewJobs(string searchString="",decimal? BudgetMin=0,decimal? BudgetMax=0,string location="")
    {
        List<Gig> gigs = new List<Gig>();
        AdminPanel admin = new AdminPanel();
        gigs = admin.GetAllGigData();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.GigTagLine.Contains(searchString) || s.GigDescription.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
        }
        if (BudgetMin != 0 && BudgetMax !=0)
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.Budget >= BudgetMin && s.Budget <= BudgetMax).ToList();
        }

        if (BudgetMin != 0 && BudgetMax == 0)
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.Budget >= BudgetMin).ToList();
        }
        if (BudgetMin != 0 && BudgetMax == 0)
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.Budget >= BudgetMin).ToList();
        }

        if (BudgetMax != 0 && BudgetMin == 0)
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.Budget <= BudgetMax).ToList();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
        {
            gigs = gigs.Where(s => s.Location.Contains(location)).ToList();
        }


        return View(gigs);
    }
```

Well right now my search is working on only one field at a time. The fields that i have in my database table are Location,GigTagline,Budget and Eventdate. How do i make my search much more effective and fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Defer Query Execution (remove ToLists)**

For a start, assuming you are using EF or a similar ORM, remove those `ToList()` calls.

Instead, make `gigs` an `IQueryable<Gig>` and make your `GetAllGigData` method return `gigs` as an `IQueryable` (i.e. don't `ToList()` anywhere in there either).

Then at the end you can `ToList()` before passing to the view.

This will mean all the `Where` clauses are applied together at the database and performed as a single call, rather than pulling back all `gigs` into memory.

**Simplify Budget Check**

Second, you can simplify your Budget checks (for readability, not necessarily performance).

Try:

```
gigs = gigs.Where(s => (BudgetMax == 0 || s.Budget <= BudgetMax) && 
                      (BudgetMin == 0 || s.Budget >= BudgetMin));
```

**Check either Tag Line and Description (not both)**

Third, do you really want *both* the Tag Line and Description to contain the search term (not just one or other other?). You could fix this using an `or` rather than an `and`.

It might be faster to concatenate the two (e.g. `(g.TagLine + " " + g.Description).Contains(search)`) but I haven't done the test to verify that.

**Search for each word, not the whole ordered sentence**

Fourth, I tend to break up text searches into words, and make sure each word matches (rather than the full sentence). This allows "cars Melbourne" to match "Find the best cars in Melbourne" and "Melbourne Cars For Sale", which your current search would not do. This seems particularly appropriate for you given your Tag Lines. However, it does mean you will get more noise (unintentional results) in your query.

One way to do this would be:

```
searchString = searchString ?? String.Empty;

// Might want to strip out non-hyphen punctuation here?

string[] searchWords = searchString.Split(' ') // Split on spaces
                   .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)); // Remove empty

if (searchWords.Any())
{
    // Make sure that every search word is contained in 
    // either the Tag Line or Description
    gigs = gigs.Where(g => searchWords.All(w => 
                             (g.GigTagLine.Contains(w) 
                              || g.GigDescription.Contains(w))));   

    // This loops over each Gig (g)
    // and then for each Gig it loops over each Search Word (w)
    // and then for each Search Word it checks if it's in the Tags or Desc
}
```

**Consider sort order**

In my past experience, sorting is a far more important problem that filtering. Consider searching online for a "Wikipedia". There would be millions of results, all completely relevant. However, the actual Wikipedia site is the one most want. As you'd know search engines have far more complex rules on how they achieve this (references from other sites, detecting what people click, etc.).

In your case you're unlikely to have as much data. Generally I'd sort by something relevant to the domain, e.g. Price (cheapest gig first), Popularity (sales/tickets for past shows or current gig), Date (earliest gig first).

On a real estate site you'll generally have people select their preferred sort order. I'd say for gigs, sorting by gig date (to have the soonest first) would probably do the job.

You could do this with (not knowing your database) `gigs = gigs.OrderBy(g => g.GigDate)`.

**(Later) Consider full-text Search**

Finally, if you are really keen on improving the full-text search, there are packages out there that might be useful, including Lucene.NET or others mentioned on SO. It's unlikely to be necessary right now, but I don't know all of your context and it might be useful down the track (when you have a LOT of text/gigs and a decent amount of searches). These tools often facilitate "smarter" searches rather than just 'contains'. Something to think about if these initial changes are still really unsatisfying.

For now I'd try something like the following:

```
public ActionResult ViewJobs(string searchString="", decimal? BudgetMin=0, 
                  decimal? BudgetMax=0, string location="")
{
    AdminPanel admin = new AdminPanel();
    IQueryable<Gig> gigs = admin.GetAllGigData();

    /* Text Filtering */

    searchString = searchString ?? String.Empty;
    string[] searchWords = searchString.Split(' ') // Split on spaces
               .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)); // Remove empty

    if (searchWords.Any())
    {
        // Make sure that every search word is contained in 
        // either the Tag Line or Description
        gigs = gigs.Where(g => searchWords.All(w => 
                                 (g.GigTagLine.Contains(w) 
                                  || g.GigDescription.Contains(w)))); 
    }

    /* Budget Filtering */
    gigs = gigs.Where(g => (BudgetMax == 0 || g.Budget <= BudgetMax) && 
                           (BudgetMin == 0 || g.Budget >= BudgetMin));

    /* Location Filtering */
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
    {
        gigs = gigs.Where(g => g.Location.Contains(location));
    }

    /* Sorting */
    gigs = gigs.OrderBy(g => g.GigDate);

    /* Execute query and render */
    return View(gigs.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Brilliant .. I am having a look at elasticsearch and free text search to optimise my search